# Unable to enter the for loop in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

```
public class StdQuoteSummaryCreationHandler{

public static void createICMQuoteSummaryRecords(Set<Id> quoteIds)
{
    Map<String,List<QuoteLineItem>> quotelineMap=new Map<String,List<QuoteLineItem>>();
    Map<String,List<Quote_Summary__c>> quoteICMSummaryMap=new Map<String,List<Quote_Summary__c>>();
    List<QuoteLineItem> qlineList;
    List<Quote_Summary__c> qlistICMSummary;
    List<Quote_Summary__c> qlistICMSummarytodelete;
    List<Quote_Summary__c> qlistICMSummaryAll=new List<Quote_Summary__c>();
    Set<String> quoteToUpdate=new Set<String>();
    List<Quote> quotelist=[SELECT Id,Currency__c,ICM_Summary_Created__c,DH_StartDate__c,DH_EndDate__c,DH_SubscriptionTerm__c,DH_Ramp__c FROM Quote WHERE Id IN:quoteIds];
    for(QuoteLineItem sbqlineItem : [SELECT Id,QuoteId,ACVLicensePS__c,Product2.Global_Local__c,Product2.Family,DH_Period__c,DH_Start_date__c,DH_End_Date__c,DH_Net_Price__c,ProductFamily__c,Term_Type__c,DealHub_QuoteLine_Ramp__c  
                                     FROM QuoteLineItem WHERE QuoteId IN:quoteIds])
                                          
    {
        
        if(quotelineMap.ContainsKey(sbqlineItem.QuoteId)) {
           quotelineMap.get(sbqlineItem.QuoteId).add(sbqlineItem);
            
        }
        else
        {
            quotelineMap.put(sbqlineItem.QuoteId,new List<QuoteLineItem>());
            quotelineMap.get(sbqlineItem.QuoteId).add(sbqlineItem);
        }              
    }
    
    for(Quote sbq:quotelist)
    {       
        system.debug('quotelist:::::::::' +quotelist);
        if(quotelineMap.ContainsKey(sbq.Id))
        {
            qlineList=new List<QuoteLineItem>();
            qlistICMSummary=new List<Quote_Summary__c>();
            qlistICMSummarytodelete=new List<Quote_Summary__c>([select id from Quote_Summary__c where DH_Quote__c =:sbq.id]);
            if(qlistICMSummarytodelete.size()>0){
                    Database.delete(qlistICMSummarytodelete, false);
                }
            for(QuoteLineItem lineItem:quotelineMap.get(sbq.ID))
            { 
                qlineList.add(lineItem);
            }
            system.debug('qlineList' +qlineList);
            if(qlineList.size()>0){
                    qlistICMSummary=U4_GetICMRecordsForQuote.createICMQuoteSummary(sbq.Id,sbq.DH_StartDate__c,sbq.DH_EndDate__c,sbq.DH_SubscriptionTerm__c,sbq.DH_Ramp__c,qlineList,sbq.Currency__c);
                    system.debug('qlistICMSummary@@@@@' +qlistICMSummary);
            }
            if(qlistICMSummary.size()>0)
            {
                for(Quote_Summary__c qsummary:qlistICMSummary)
                {
                    qlistICMSummaryAll.add(qsummary);
                }
                quoteToUpdate.add(sbq.id);
            }
        }
    }
    if(qlistICMSummaryAll.size()>0)
        try{
            insert qlistICMSummaryAll;
        }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        U4_ServiceCloud_Utility.CreateSCLog('Quote_Summary__c','', System.UserInfo.getUserId(),'Info','U4_ICMQuoteStdSummaryCreationHandler.insertquoteSummaryList',ex.getMessage().substring(0, 254));
    }
}

public static void sendICMQuoteSummaryToICMAzure(Set<Id> quoteIds)
{
    AzureServiceBusConfigDetails__mdt asbconfigDetail = [SELECT MasterLabel, Namespace__c, Topic__c ,SASKeyName__c,SASKeyValue__c FROM AzureServiceBusConfigDetails__mdt WHERE MasterLabel ='ICM ASB Configuration' LIMIT 1];        
    
    Set<String> oppIds= new Set<String>();
    List<Quote> quoteToProcess=[SELECT Id,OpportunityId FROM Quote WHERE ID IN:quoteIds];
    for(Quote sbq : quoteToProcess)
    {                    
        oppIds.add(sbq.OpportunityId);    
    } 
    Map<String,List<Quote>> oppquoteMap =new Map<String,List<Quote>>();        
    for(Quote oppQuoteInfo : [SELECT Id,OpportunityId,
                                       DH_SubscriptionTerm__c,
                                       Unit4_Company_Name__c, Unit4_street__c, Unit4_country__c,
                                       BillingCountry,
                                       AccountId,Account.Name,DH_CSR_First_Name__c,DH_CSRLastName__c,
                                       DH_CSR_Email__c,
                                       CurrencyIsoCode,
                                       LastModifiedDate,Aggregated_TCV_SaaS_non_ramped__c,Aggregate_TCV_License_Maintenece_Supp__c,
                                       Aggregated_TCV_Summary__c,TCV_Professional_Services__c,DH_Ramp__c,
                                       ICM_Min_Indexation_Rate__c,ICM_Indexation_Rate_Increase__c,ICM_ExpiryDate__c,DH_StartDate__c,DH_BillingFrequency__c,
                                       Email,ExpirationDate,DH_PONumber__c,DH_Quote_Id__c,Status,ICM_DeliveryMethod__c,
                                       ICM_EffectiveDate__c,ICM_ProductType__c,BillingStreet,BillingName,
                                       Unit4_Postal_Code__c,BillingCity,BillingState,BillingPostalCode,
                                       DH_PaymentTerms__c,ICM_SysID__c,
                                       (SELECT Id, DH_HeadProduct__c,ProductName__c,ProductFamily__c,
                                        ProductCode__c,DH_Quantity__c,DH_Unit_OfMeasure__c,DH_List_Price__c,
                                        Discount,currencyisocode,DealHub_QuoteLine_Ramp__c,DH_Period__c
                                         FROM QuoteLineItems),
                                       (SELECT Id,Aggregate_for_PF__c,Component__c,End_Date__c,Product_Family__c,
                                        PS_Scope__c,DH_Quote__c,Segment__c,Start_Date__c,TCV__c,
                                        Term_type__c,Year__c,CurrencyIsoCode FROM Quote_Summarys__r) from Quote where OpportunityId 
                                       IN:oppIds AND Status=:System.Label.Approval_Status_Approved order by LastModifiedDate DESC])
    {
        if(oppquoteMap.ContainsKey(oppQuoteInfo.OpportunityId)) {
            oppquoteMap.get(oppQuoteInfo.OpportunityId).add(oppQuoteInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            oppquoteMap.put(oppQuoteInfo.OpportunityId,new List<Quote>());
            oppquoteMap.get(oppQuoteInfo.OpportunityId).add(oppQuoteInfo);
        }
    }
    
    for(Quote sbq : quoteToProcess)
    { 
        if(oppquoteMap.ContainsKey(sbq.OpportunityId))
        {             
            PrepareAndSendMessageToAzure(sbq.Id,oppquoteMap.get(sbq.OpportunityId),asbconfigDetail);
        }
    }   
    
}


@TestVisible   
private static void PrepareAndSendMessageToAzure(String quoteId,List<Quote> oppquoteinfo,AzureServiceBusConfigDetails__mdt asbConfigDetail)
{
    
    String oldquoteId;
    String action='add';
    Quote quote;
    Integer oppquoteinfoSize=oppQuoteinfo.size();
    if(oppquoteinfoSize>1)
    {
        oldquoteId=oppQuoteinfo[1].Id;
        action='update';
    }
    for(Quote quoteInfo:oppquoteinfo)
    {
        if(quoteInfo.Id==quoteId)
        {
            quote=quoteInfo;
            break;
        }
    }
    JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
    gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeStringField('EventType','QuoteToAgreementSync'); 
    gen.writeStringField('Action',action);
    gen.writeStringField('User',userInfo.getUserId());
    gen.writeFieldName('Data');
    gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeFieldName('sfEntityInfo');
    gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeStringField('OpportunityId',(quote.OpportunityId!=null)?quote.OpportunityId:''); 
    //gen.writeStringField('OldQuoteId', (oldquoteId!=null)?oldquoteId:'');
    if(oldquoteId!=null)
        gen.writeStringField('OldQuoteId',oldquoteId);
    else
        gen.writeNullField('OldQuoteId');
    gen.writeStringField('NewQuoteId',(quote.id!=null)?quote.id:'');
    if(quote.Aggregated_TCV_SaaS_non_ramped__c!=null)
        gen.writeNumberField('Aggregated_tcv_saas_non_ramped__c',quote.Aggregated_TCV_SaaS_non_ramped__c);
    else
        gen.writeNullField('Aggregated_tcv_saas_non_ramped__c');
    if(quote.Aggregate_TCV_License_Maintenece_Supp__c!=null)
        gen.writeNumberField('Aggregate_tcv_license_maintenece_supp__c',quote.Aggregate_TCV_License_Maintenece_Supp__c);
    else
        gen.writeNullField('Aggregate_tcv_license_maintenece_supp__c');        
    if(quote.TCV_Professional_Services__c!=null)
        gen.writeNumberField('Tcv_professional_services__c',quote.TCV_Professional_Services__c);
    else
        gen.writeNullField('Tcv_professional_services__c');
    gen.writeStringField('AccountId', (quote.AccountId!=null)?quote.AccountId:'');
    gen.writeBooleanField('DH_Ramp__c',(quote.DH_Ramp__c!=null)?quote.DH_Ramp__c:false);
    if(quote.ICM_Min_Indexation_Rate__c!=null)
        gen.writeStringField('ICM_Min_Indexation_Rate__c',quote.ICM_Min_Indexation_Rate__c);
    else
        gen.writeNullField('ICM_Min_Indexation_Rate__c');
    if(quote.ICM_Indexation_Rate_Increase__c!=null)
        gen.writeStringField('ICM_Indexation_Rate_Increase__c',quote.ICM_Indexation_Rate_Increase__c);
    else
        gen.writeNullField('ICM_Indexation_Rate_Increase__c');
    if(quote.DH_StartDate__c!=null)
        gen.writeDateField('DH_StartDate__c',quote.DH_StartDate__c);
    else
        gen.writeStringField('DH_StartDate__c','');           
    
    gen.writeStringField('DH_BillingFrequency__c', (quote.DH_BillingFrequency__c!=null)?quote.DH_BillingFrequency__c:'');
  //  gen.writeStringField('Unit4_taxid__c', (quote.Unit4_TaxId__c!=null)?quote.Unit4_TaxId__c:'');
    gen.writeStringField('Email', (quote.Email!=null)?quote.Email:'');
    if(quote.ExpirationDate!=null)
        gen.writeDateField('ExpirationDate',quote.ExpirationDate);
    else
        gen.writeStringField('ExpirationDate','');
    
    gen.writeStringField('DH_PONumber__c', (quote.DH_PONumber__c!=null)?quote.DH_PONumber__c:'');
    gen.writeStringField('DH_Quote_Id__c', (quote.DH_Quote_Id__c!=null)?quote.DH_Quote_Id__c:'');
    gen.writeStringField('Status', (quote.Status!=null)?quote.Status:'');        
    gen.writeStringField('Icm_deliverymethod__c', (quote.ICM_DeliveryMethod__c!=null)?quote.ICM_DeliveryMethod__c:'');
    if(quote.ICM_ExpiryDate__c!=null)
        gen.writeDateField('Icm_expirydate__c',quote.ICM_ExpiryDate__c);
    else
        gen.writeStringField('Icm_expirydate__c','');  
    if(quote.ICM_EffectiveDate__c!=null)
        gen.writeDateField('Icm_effectivedate__c',quote.ICM_EffectiveDate__c);
    else
        gen.writeStringField('Icm_effectivedate__c','');
   // gen.writeStringField('Icm_contractdocumentname__c', (quote.ICM_ContractDocumentName__c!=null)?quote.ICM_ContractDocumentName__c:'');        
    gen.writeStringField('Icm_producttype__c', (quote.ICM_ProductType__c!=null)?quote.ICM_ProductType__c:'');        
    gen.writeStringField('BillingStreet', (quote.BillingStreet!=null)?quote.BillingStreet:'');        
    gen.writeStringField('BillingName', (quote.BillingName!=null)?quote.BillingName:'');        
    gen.writeStringField('Unit4_Postal_Code__c', (quote.Unit4_Postal_Code__c!=null)?quote.Unit4_Postal_Code__c:'');        
    
    gen.writeStringField('BillingCity', (quote.BillingCity!=null)?quote.BillingCity:'');        
    gen.writeStringField('BillingState', (quote.BillingState!=null)?quote.BillingState:'');
    gen.writeStringField('BillingPostalCode', (quote.BillingPostalCode!=null)?quote.BillingPostalCode:'');
    gen.writeStringField('DH_PaymentTerms__c', (quote.DH_PaymentTerms__c!=null)?quote.DH_PaymentTerms__c:'');
    gen.writeStringField('Unit4_Company_Name__c', (quote.Unit4_Company_Name__c!=null)?quote.Unit4_Company_Name__c:'');
    gen.writeStringField('ICM_SysID__c', (quote.ICM_SysID__c!=null)?quote.ICM_SysID__c:'');
   // gen.writeStringField('Region__c', (quote.Region__c!=null)?quote.Region__c:''); 
    if(quote.Aggregated_TCV_Summary__c!=null)
        gen.writeNumberField('Aggregated_TCV_Summary__c',quote.Aggregated_TCV_Summary__c);
    else
        gen.writeNullField('Aggregated_TCV_Summary__c');
    
    
    if(quote.DH_SubscriptionTerm__c!=null)
    gen.writeNumberField('DH_SubscriptionTerm__c', quote.DH_SubscriptionTerm__c);
    gen.writeStringField('Unit4_Company_Name__c',(quote.Unit4_Company_Name__c!=null)?quote.Unit4_Company_Name__c:'');
    gen.writeStringField('Unit4_street__c', (quote.Unit4_street__c!=null)?quote.Unit4_street__c:'');
    gen.writeStringField('Unit4_country__c', (quote.Unit4_country__c!=null)?quote.Unit4_country__c:'');
    gen.writeStringField('BillingCountry', (quote.BillingCountry!=null)?quote.BillingCountry:'');
    gen.writeStringField('Account.Name', (quote.Account.Name!=null)?quote.Account.Name:'');
    gen.writeStringField('DH_CSR_Email__c', (quote.DH_CSR_Email__c!=null)?quote.DH_CSR_Email__c:'');
    gen.writeStringField('DH_CSR_First_Name__c', (quote.DH_CSR_First_Name__c!=null)?quote.DH_CSR_First_Name__c:'');
    gen.writeStringField('DH_CSRLastName__c', (quote.DH_CSRLastName__c!=null)?quote.DH_CSRLastName__c:'');
    gen.writeStringField('CurrencyIsoCode',(quote.CurrencyIsoCode!=null)?quote.CurrencyIsoCode:'');
    gen.writeFieldName('QuoteLineItems');
    gen.writeStartArray();
    for(QuoteLineItem lineItem:quote.QuoteLineItems)
    {
        system.debug('lineItem'+lineItem);
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField('QuoteLineItems.DH_HeadProduct__c',(lineItem.DH_HeadProduct__c!=null)?lineItem.DH_HeadProduct__c:'');
        gen.writeStringField('QuoteLineItems.ProductName__c',(lineItem.ProductName__c!=null)?lineItem.ProductName__c:'');
        gen.writeStringField('QuoteLineItems.ProductFamily__c',(lineItem.ProductFamily__c!=null)?lineItem.ProductFamily__c:''); 
        gen.writeStringField('QuoteLineItems.ProductCode__c',(lineItem.ProductCode__c!=null)?lineItem.ProductCode__c:'');
        gen.writeBooleanField('QuoteLineItems.DealHub_QuoteLine_Ramp__c',(lineItem.DealHub_QuoteLine_Ramp__c!=null)?lineItem.DealHub_QuoteLine_Ramp__c:false);
        gen.writeStringField('QuoteLineItems.DH_Period__c',(lineItem.DH_Period__c!=null)?lineItem.DH_Period__c:'');
                
        if(lineItem.DH_Quantity__c!=null) 
            gen.writeNumberField('QuoteLineItems.DH_Quantity__c',lineItem.DH_Quantity__c); 
        gen.writeStringField('QuoteLineItems.DH_Unit_OfMeasure__c',(lineItem.DH_Unit_OfMeasure__c!=null)?lineItem.DH_Unit_OfMeasure__c:''); 
        
        if(lineItem.DH_List_Price__c!=null)                
            gen.writeNumberField('QuoteLineItems.DH_List_Price__c',lineItem.DH_List_Price__c);
        if(lineItem.Discount!=null) 
            gen.writeNumberField('QuoteLineItems.Discount',lineItem.Discount);
       
        gen.writeStringField('QuoteLineItems.currencyisocode',(lineItem.CurrencyIsoCode!=null)?lineItem.CurrencyIsoCode:''); 
        
        gen.writeStringField('QuoteLineItems.id', (lineItem.Id!=null)?lineItem.Id:'');
        
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
    gen.writeEndArray();
    
    gen.writeFieldName('Quote_Summarys__r');
    gen.writeStartArray();
    for(Quote_Summary__c qsummry:quote.Quote_Summarys__r)
    {
        system.debug('qsummry'+qsummry);
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeBooleanField('Quote_Summarys__r.Aggregate_for_PF__c',(qsummry.Aggregate_for_PF__c!=null)?qsummry.Aggregate_for_PF__c:false);
        gen.writeStringField('Quote_Summarys__r.Component__c',(qsummry.Component__c!=null)?qsummry.Component__c:'');
        if(qsummry.End_Date__c!=null)
            gen.writeDateField('Quote_Summarys__r.End_Date__c',qsummry.End_Date__c);
        else
            gen.writeStringField('Quote_Summarys__r.End_Date__c','');   
        gen.writeStringField('Quote_Summarys__r.Product_Family__c',(qsummry.Product_Family__c!=null)?qsummry.Product_Family__c:'');
        gen.writeStringField('Quote_Summarys__r.PS_Scope__c',(qsummry.PS_Scope__c!=null)?qsummry.PS_Scope__c:'');
        gen.writeStringField('Quote_Summarys__r.Segment__c',(qsummry.Segment__c!=null)?qsummry.Segment__c:'');
        if(qsummry.Start_Date__c!=null)
            gen.writeDateField('Quote_Summarys__r.Start_Date__c',qsummry.Start_Date__c);
        else
            gen.writeStringField('Quote_Summarys__r.Start_Date__c','');
        if(qsummry.TCV__c!=null)
            gen.writeNumberField('Quote_Summarys__r.TCV__c',qsummry.TCV__c);
        else
            gen.writeStringField('Quote_Summarys__r.TCV__c','');
        gen.writeStringField('Quote_Summarys__r.Term_type__c',(qsummry.Term_type__c!=null)?qsummry.Term_type__c:'');
        gen.writeStringField('Quote_Summarys__r.Year__c',(qsummry.Year__c!=null)?qsummry.Year__c:'');   
        gen.writeStringField('Quote_Summarys__r.id', (qsummry.Id!=null)?qsummry.Id:'');
        gen.writeStringField('Quote_Summarys__r.currencyisocode',(qsummry.CurrencyIsoCode!=null)?qsummry.CurrencyIsoCode:''); 
        
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
    gen.writeEndArray();        
    gen.writeEndObject();
    gen.writeEndObject();
    gen.writeEndObject();
    String jsonData = gen.getAsString();
    U4_AzureManagement u4Azr=new U4_AzureManagement(asbconfigDetail.Namespace__c,asbconfigDetail.Topic__c,asbconfigDetail.SASKeyName__c,asbconfigDetail.SASKeyValue__c);        
    u4Azr.sendMessageToQueue(jsonData);
}
}
```

The test class doesn't cover :

```
for(Quote_Summary__c qsummary:qlistICMSummary)
                {
                    qlistICMSummaryAll.add(qsummary);
                }
```

part of the code.

Test class::

```
@isTest static void quoteCreationAndApprove(){
    CPQ_TriggerSwitches__c cts = new CPQ_TriggerSwitches__c();
    cts.Quote_onBeforeInsert__c = true;
    cts.Quote_onBeforeUpdate__c = true;
    cts.Quote_onAfterInsert__c = true;
    insert cts;       
    
    Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
    Id PBcustom = Id.valueOf(System.Label.PB2020ID);
    TriggerSupport__c triggerSupport = U4_NewTestDataFactory.TEST_CreateTriggerSupport(true); 
    SCMC__Currency_Master__c SCM = U4_NewTestDataFactory.TEST_CreateSCMCurrency(False);
    SCM.Name = 'EUR';
    insert SCM;
    //Creating U4 Account
    Account account = U4_NewTestDataFactory.TEST_CreateSingleAccount(False);
    account.Name = 'Business Software Ltd.';
    account.BillingCountry = 'North America';
    insert account;
    Opportunity opportunity = CPQTestFactory.createOpportunity(account.Id, 'Opty1', PBcustom);
    opportunity.Require_DH_Quote__c = 'Yes';
    opportunity.ACV_License__c = 12;
    opportunity.Pricebook2Id = pricebookId;
    opportunity.accountid = account.id;     
    update opportunity;
    Quote qt = new Quote();
    qt.Name = 'test';
    qt.Status = 'Draft';
    qt.opportunityid = opportunity.id;
    qt.DH_StartDate__c = System.today();
    qt.DH_EndDate__c = system.today()+2;
    qt.ExpirationDate = system.today()+1;
    qt.DH_SubscriptionTerm__c = 36;
    qt.DH_Ramp__c = TRUE;
    qt.ExpirationDate = system.today()+1;
    
    insert qt;
    
    opportunity.SyncedQuoteId = qt.id;
    update opportunity;
    
    User approver = U4_NewTestDataFactory.TEST_CreateSystemAdminitrator(true);
    
    Product2 product1 = new Product2();
    product1.Name = 'testProduct';
    product1.productCode = '1234';
    product1.isActive = true;
    product1.CurrencyIsoCode = 'EUR';            
    product1.U4_Product_Family__c = 'testFamily';
    product1.ProductCode = 'PCode';
    product1.Unit_of_Measure__c = 'number of FTE employees';
    product1.SBQQ__Component__c = true;
    product1.SbQQ__hidden__c = false;        
    insert product1;
    
    
    // 1. Insert a price book entry for the standard price book.
    // Standard price book entries require the standard price book ID we got earlier.
    PricebookEntry standardPrice = new PricebookEntry(
    Pricebook2Id = pricebookId, Product2Id = product1.Id,
    UnitPrice = 1000, IsActive = true);
    insert standardPrice;
    
    PriceBook2 pb2=new PriceBook2();
    pb2.Name = 'test';
    pb2.IsActive = true;
    pb2.CurrencyIsoCode='EUR';
    
    insert pb2;
           
     
    PricebookEntry pbe = New PricebookEntry ();
    pbe = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = pb2.Id, Product2Id = product1.Id, UnitPrice = 10000, IsActive = true, UseStandardPrice = false);
    insert pbe;
    
    QuoteLineItem testQuoteline = new QuoteLineItem (
        Quoteid = qt.id, 
        Product2id = product1.id,
        Quantity = 22,
        PricebookEntryId = standardPrice.id,
        UnitPrice = 200,
        DH_Quantity__c = 10,
        DH_List_Price__c = 10.0,
        Discount= 2);
    insert testQuoteline;
    //qt.Status = 'In Approval Process';
   // update qt;
    Quote_Summary__c qs = new Quote_Summary__c();
    qs.Aggregate_for_PF__c = false;
    qs.Component__c = 'non ramped';
    qs.Start_Date__c = system.today(); 
    qs.End_Date__c  = system.today() + 5;
    qs.TCV__c = 4400;
    qs.DH_Quote__c = qt.id;
    insert qs;
    
    qt.Status = 'Approved';
    qt.ICM_EffectiveDate__c = system.today();
    qt.ICM_ExpiryDate__c = system.today()+2;
    update qt;
    
    
    
    List<Quote> quoteList=new List<Quote>();
    quoteList.add(qt);
    Set<Id> quoteIds = new Set<Id>();
    quoteIds.add(qt.id);
    
    
  
    AzureServiceBusConfigDetails__mdt asbconfigDetail = [SELECT MasterLabel, Namespace__c, Topic__c ,SASKeyName__c,SASKeyValue__c FROM AzureServiceBusConfigDetails__mdt WHERE MasterLabel ='ICM ASB Configuration' LIMIT 1];     
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new U4_AzureManagementCallOutMock());
    Test.startTest(); 
    U4_ICMStdQuoteToAzurePBHandler.sendQuoteToASB(quoteList);
    StdQuoteSummaryCreationHandler.createICMQuoteSummaryRecords(quoteIds);
    QuoteSummaryCreationHandler.sendICMQuoteSummaryToICMAzure(quoteIds);
    
    
    test.stopTest();
}
```

Comment: what's the method U4_GetICMRecordsForQuote.createICMQuoteSummary doing? Seems like it's returning an empty list.

Comment: Its creates the Quote Summary object records

Comment: Did you check the debugger to see if it's actually returning something? Seems like that's the root cause of your issue.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that @nicolas has identified the likely proximate cause, but this question doesn't contain enough information to offer a complete solution. I've linked this question to our canonical question about code coverage, which does explain this general pattern.